# Silver identification of the group I of cations

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I was wondering if this actually happens in a chemical reaction
$$\ce{AgCl_{(s)} + 2NH_4OH_{(aq)} \rightleftharpoons  Ag(NH_3)_{2(aq)}^+ + Cl^{-}_{(aq)} + 2H_2O_{(l)}}$$
My teacher wrote something like this but on Internet I saw that it yields to $\ce{Ag(NH_3)_2Cl}$ and water, so can someone explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both formulas for diamminesilver(I) chloride essentially mean the same. Writing it as

$$\ce{Ag(NH_3)_{2(aq)}^+ + Cl^{-}_{(aq)}}$$ emphasizes that the compound is dissolved in water as discrete ions (the cationic silver complex and chloride anions). One can also write $\ce{Ag(NH_3)_2Cl}$ instead because it is known that the compound exists in the aforementioned way in aqueous solution. In the latter case, it would still be more precise to use brackets to indicate the complex, i.e. $[\ce{Ag(NH3)2}]\ce{Cl}$, so that it becomes clear that the two $\ce{NH3}$ are the ligands of silver.

Comment: Now everything makes sense, I'm sorry but how does the color change after the reaction?

Comment: @user162485 The white precipitate of AgCl will dissolve to form a colorless solution of diamminsilver(I) chloride.